# Header Location not working inside Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the same code in 2 servers but the "Header Location" only works in one of them.

**Facts:**

- Header Location works on both outside Laravel framework
- Header Location works only on server 1 inside Laravel
- Redirect::to() works on both!

How can I use redirect or something similar in views?

if I use exit('header.. or die, it works but session vars are lost, weird!

Comment: Can you use conditional checking to determine what syntax to use depending on what server you are on? Are these both in the Laravel framework?

Comment: one just doesn't redirect from views when using MVC frameworks. He uses the controller for this before any output is sent.

Comment: Shouldn't `header("Location: url")` always work regardless of what framework is being used?

Comment: Dont know whats conditional checking?; yes both in Laravel; yes it should work so I thing its a Laravels bug for some servers config. New: if I use exit(header.. or die, is works but session vars are lost, weird!